# Grid inside a grid Javascript and JQuery:

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to have a small grid drawn inside of a larger grid. Using zIndex doesn't seem to work at all and I'm out of ideas.

Code for drawing the grid

Javascript/JQuery:

```
function creategrid(size){

          var primeW = Math.floor((400) / size),
              primeH = Math.floor((250) / size),
              standardW = Math.floor((500) / size),
              standardH = Math.floor((500) / size);

          var standard = document.createElement('div');
              standard.className = 'grid';
              standard.style.width = (standardW * size) + 'px';
              standard.style.height = (standardH * size) + 'px';

          var prime = document.createElement('div');
              prime.clasName = 'gridprime';
              prime.style.width = (primeW * size) + 'px';
              prime.style.height = (primeH * size)+ 'px';
              prime.style.zIndex= '-1';
              standard.appendChild(prime);

            for (var i = 0; i < standardH; i++) {
                for (var p = 0; p < standardW; p++) {
                  var cell = document.createElement('div');
                      cell.style.height = (size - 1) + 'px';
                      cell.style.width = (size - 1) + 'px';
                      cell.style.zIndex= '10';
                      standard.appendChild(cell);
                }
            }

          document.body.appendChild(standard);
        }

creategrid(10);
```

CSS for telling the grids apart.

CSS:

```
  .grid {
    margin: 0px auto auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    background-color: #28ACF9;
  }

  .grid div {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
    float: left;
  }

  .gridprime {
    margin-top: 50px ;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #FFFF33;
    float: left;
  }
```

Right now the prime grid is either hidden or not loading the css assigned to it, the only way that you can tell it's there is by the fact that it displaces the cells.

Ideally the cells will sit on top of the standard and prime grids, and the prime grid will correctly use the defined styles.

## **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MJpf/4/)**

Comment: First of all, you've misspelled `className` for the prime grid.

Comment: and that's sorted the css not being loaded. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed a

```
prime.style.position = 'absolute'
```

and

```
cell.style.positon = 'relative'
```

added to your z-indexes.

Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/7MJpf/5/

Comment: Thanks, that's sorted the cells being displaced. Still stuck on how to get the prime grid to appear in the correct colours and with a border from the css.

Comment: what colors and borders are you attempting to get?

Comment: it's been sorted... I managed to make a spelling mistake in className for prime. Thank you though

Comment: Good deal, glad you got it.